# jQuery.ajax not passing value to php variable

Tags: javascript

this is my code for inputting value from a form to a javascript variable and hopefully to transfer it to a php variable..but it outputs nothing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function swapImage(id, primary, secondary,ide) {        


    src = document.getElementById(id).src;

    var allNone = true;

    var arr = new Array();

    arr = document.getElementById(ide);   

    if (src.match(primary)) {

            for(var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i-=1) {                 

            if (arr.value != "none"){                                                                                                            

                        jQuery(function(){                                
                               jQuery.ajax({
                                    url: 'blog.php',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    data: {
                                        jM:  $('#jumpMenu  option:selected').val(),
                                        jM2: $('#jumpMenu2 option:selected').val(),
                                        jM3: $('#jumpMenu3 option:selected').val(),
                                        jM4: $('#jumpMenu4 option:selected').val(),
                                        jM5: $('#jumpMenu5 option:selected').val(),
                                        jM6: $('#jumpMenu6 option:selected').val(),
                                        jM7: $('#jumpMenu7 option:selected').val(),
                                        jM8: $('#jumpMenu8 option:selected').val(),
                                        jM9: $('#jumpMenu9 option:selected').val(),
                                    },

                                    success: function(result){
                                        alert(result);

                                    },
                                    error: function(results) {
                                        console.log('Error:');
                                        console.log(results);
                                    }
                                });

                        });  

                        document.getElementById(id).src=secondary;
                        allNone = false;

                        break;                                                         
                    } 

            }
              if (allNone)
                {
                    alert("You must specify the item's size!");
                }

    } else {                                     
        location.href = 'blog.php';
    }
```

}

here is the php code for the other webpage

```
Did you type "<?php 
   $jM1 = isset($_POST['jM'])? $_POST['jM'] : '' ; 
    $jM2 = isset($_POST['jM2'])? $_POST['jM2'] : '';
    $jM3 = isset($_POST['jM3'])? $_POST['jM3'] : '';
    $jM4 = isset($_POST['jM4'])? $_POST['jM4'] : '';
    $jM5 = isset($_POST['jM5'])? $_POST['jM5'] : '';
    $jM6 = isset($_POST['jM6'])? $_POST['jM6'] : '';
    $jM7 = isset($_POST['jM7'])? $_POST['jM7'] : '';
    $jM8 = isset($_POST['jM8'])? $_POST['jM8'] : '';
    $jM9 = isset($_POST['jM9'])? $_POST['jM9'] : '';

    echo $jM1."<br />".$jM2."<br />".$jM3; 
    ?>" for?
```

the output was like this one: "Did you type ""?".This was updated..i can get the result from the alert messagebox however i cant output in from the blog.php

here is the html code:

```
 <th height="464" scope="col"><img src="images/three.jpg" width="304" height="363" class = "tilt pic" />
        <table width="200" border="0" align="center">
          <tr>
            <th width="63">Price:</th>
            <th width="127"><?php echo $final_array[0][1]; ?></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>         
            <th>Size:</th>
            <form method="post" name="form" id="form">
            <th><select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu" class="jM">
                <option value ="none">Enter Item Size</option>
                <option value ="6">Small</option>
                <option value ="8">Medium</option>
                <option value ="10">Large</option>
                <option value ="12">Extra Large</option>
                <option value ="14">XX Large</option>
              </select>
            </th>               
                <th><img                      
                    src="images/submit.gif" name="tadi"
                    id="tadi"
                    title="View Order"
                    onclick="swapImage(
                      'tadi',
                      'images/submit.gif',
                      'images/so.gif',
                      'jumpMenu'
                    )"
                  />           

          </th>

            </form>
          </tr>
      </table>


      </th>
      <th scope="col"><img src="images/two.jpg" width="304" height="363" class = "tilt pic" />
         <table width="200" border="0" align="center">
          <tr>
            <th width="63">Price:</th>
            <th width="127"> <?php echo $final_array[0][1]; ?></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <th>Size:</th>
            <form method="post" name="form" id="form" action="blog.php">
            <th>  <select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu2" class="jM2">
                <option value ="none">Enter Item Size</option>
                <option value ="6">Small</option>
                <option value ="8">Medium</option>
                <option value ="10">Large</option>
                <option value ="12">Extra Large</option>
                <option value ="14">XX Large</option>
              </select>
            </th>
            <th><img
                    id="change"
                    onclick="swapImage(
                      'change',
                      'images/submit.gif',
                      'images/so.gif',
                      'jumpMenu2'
                    )"                      
                    src="images/submit.gif"
                    title="View Order"
                  />  
            </th>

            </form>
          </tr>
      </table>
           </th>
```

Comment: Have you heard of arrays? They're really nifty when you have 10 variables that are to be processed in exactly the same way.

Comment: heard of it but dont know how to apply it here

Comment: It looks like you could use the `.serialize()` jQuery method and just pass the entire form to your server. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: sorry cause honestly im just a beginner trying to combine codes that i get from the net and books

Comment: ahm can you please explain how .serialize works in a much more understandable way..i cant quite understand the description on the link you have given..

Comment: In that case I need to see your HTML code!

Comment: ill include it on the question box..

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be in your selectors (I haven't tested it). You want the value of the select element, not the value of an option. So isntead of

```
$('#jumpMenu6 option:selected').val()
```

try:

```
$('#jumpMenu6').val()
```

Comment: it has the same output..but still the php variable which it was meant to be passed has no value when i was directed to the 'blog.php' page

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to combine synchronous behavior with asynchronous.

First of, what do you want to do with the data after is being submitted - I doubt is just alert the result();
And second, whatever the answer - you should write the code for it in the success callback function of AJAX.

Also, I might be mistaken, but from you question I understand that you are going to blog.php and expect to see the output variable?! That's never going to happen because you don't pass a $_POST['jm*'] variable just by accessing the blog.php url in your browser - that's why you use AJAX, to POST these variables.

Comment: well you got it all right..i got this codes from my recent questions here in stackoverflow and honestly i dont know how to use ajax to POST these varaibles so that the blog.php can access these javascript variables..

Comment: Alright then, let me know exactly what do you want to do after you click submit, and I'll try to help you all the way.

Comment: if you click submit..it will be replace by a new submit image button:here is the code document.getElementById(id).src=secondary;..during the replacement, the value from the <select> tag will be stored in those variables, here is the code: jM:  $('#jumpMenu  option:selected').val(), and i have 9 <select>/dropdown menu..so if you click the new submit image button the values stored on those variables will be passed on to a php variables then blog.php will now access those variables when you are directed to that page..

Comment: The way you want to do it seems a little over complicated. Why don't you store those vars in JS only, and when you are ready for the final submit you pass everything to php.

Comment: well thats what im trying to do..ahm i doing an ordering website or simply a dress for sale website and my main page was full of dress images with prices in a textbox,dropdown menu and a submit button in each..so when the user wants only 2 clothes,he can specify the size through the dropdown menu then click on submit then the new image button appears.that new image button will direct the user to view all the clothes that he bought.so until the user clicks either one of the new image button, the value from those dropdown menu IF selected will be stored in a js variable..then pass to phpvariable